# Inter-codon mutations statistical analysis

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, mutations, nucleic-acids, codon

I am looking for a statistical approach to inter-codon mutations. For example a 64*64 (64*63 actually) table, that contain the possibility of mutation from one codon to another codon (CCA to CAA or CGG... for example).

Is there any articles, databases or others that provide such table?

Please comment if my question is not completely clear.
I searched but didn't find an answer for this question in Google Scholar.

Comment: Yes and they are called [substitution matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_matrix). You might find some more information in this [review](http://www.els.net/WileyCDA/ElsArticle/refId-a0005265.html).

Comment: @cagliari2005 I don't know if you're still active on the site, but this comment is IMO worth converting to an answer.